# CMIS support for Sharepoint and OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, cmis, opencmis

I would like to have a quick info whether ***Microsoft Sharepoint and OneDrive*** has CMIS support ? If not which will be the best library to integrate Sharepoint and OneDrive using Java ?! Please help

Comment: The CMIS protocol is not supported for SharePoint online/Office 365 or OneDrive.SharePoint 2013 (on premesis) supports CMIS v1.0 according to this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945829.aspx.

Comment: @RyanGregg : I would like to have a proper java client for onedrive and sharepoint. Which will be apt for my requirement ? I see some projects in git.

Comment: There is no official JVM client available right now. There's an Android client SDK that may be useful as a starting point, or there are some other 3rd party implemented SDKs for OneDrive API in Java that you may find via your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft SharePoint on premise (2010 & 2013) supports CMIS for searching documents though limited to library level. But I have doubts regarding OneDrive files. Though OneDrive is hosted as SharePoint MySite, these documents are not accessed through SharePoint library.

Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945829.aspx) to know about CMIS on SharePoint.

And this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59189/how-to-activate-and-use-cmis-for-a-sharepoint-2013-server) to activate and use CMIS.